# Are cyclic relationships in SQL inherently wrong?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

**I'm aware that this is a topic which has been touched on a number of times. However, I haven't yet found a question/answer which discusses cyclic relationships *in general* rather than in a particular case.**

---

Suppose that I want to model a fairly straightforward situation: teams competing in a given sport. Each team can have either one captain or no captain; each player can belong to either one team or no team.

Suppose I add two tables to an empty database using the following code. (I'm most familiar with **SQLite**, so that's the syntax I've gone with.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE Team (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    captain INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(captain) REFERENCES Player(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    team INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(team) REFERENCES Team(id)
);
```

Now let's begin adding data with the following code:

```sql
INSERT INTO Player (id, full_name) VALUES (1, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO Team (id, team_name, captain) VALUES (1, 'Team Bob', 1);
UPDATE Player SET team = 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

The above code runs without error, and it does what I want it to do. The database design makes sense - at least on an intuitive level. **But is there something wrong with the dessign, perhaps  due to the cyclic relationship between the two tables?**

I understand that, in **Object-Oriented Programming** (OOP), cyclic dependencies are something to be avoided in pretty much all circumstances. OOP and database design are not unrelated topics, but does it then follow that cyclic relationships are also to be avoided universally?

---

I suppose I *could* redesign the above database as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Team (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TeamCaptain (
    team INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    captain INTEGER UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY(team) REFERENCES Team(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(captain) REFERENCES Player(id)
);
```

However, I can see the following issues with this:

- It involves adding an extra table.
- It makes the design less intuitive.
- The cyclic relationship is arguably obfuscated, rather than removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the relationship that you describe.  It gets tricky if you require that a team have a captain (i.e. the column is `NOT NULL`) because then:

- You cannot add a team without a captain.
- You cannot have a captain because there are no players (until the team exists).

There are other ways to handle this, such as an `players.is_captain` column with a filtered unique index.  But your method is fine.

Answer (score 3):

We can't say that cyclical references are always "wrong." There are very few, if any, things in code design that are that unequivocal.

Even the dreaded GOTO has some legitimate uses.

Another example might be division by zero. Yes, division by zero is undefined so we should avoid dividing by zero. But that doesn't mean we should avoid *all* use of the division operator. It just means we should be careful to ensure the divisor is not zero.

Gordon Linoff describes some special care you have to take when creating entities with cyclic references.

Comment: I think you mean ***divisor***. Having a dividend of zero - the dividend being the upper part of a fraction - would not, in and of itself, be problematic. Otherwise great answer though!

Answer (score 0):

There are issues to be concerned about in both designs.

The 1st is easier to understand and manipulate, but what about the constraint that the captain of a team must also belong to that team?
As it is, there is no constraint about that.
You could set the captain of a team to any player's id, even if that player does not belong to that team.
Sure, you could set this constraint at the application level, but it would be safer if it was set by design and as it is, it would require a trigger (which is not something bad, on the contrary it is common practice).

Your 2nd design uses an associative table, which is also common practice.
I would reject it, not because, as you say, it is *less intuitive*, but because it would add an extra table just for the simple requirement to define the captain of the team.

Also consider this design:

```
CREATE TABLE Team (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TeamPlayer (
    team_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    player_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    is_captain INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK(is_captain IN (0, 1)), 
    FOREIGN KEY(team_id) REFERENCES Team(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(player_id) REFERENCES Player(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(team_id, player_id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_teamplayer_captain 
ON TeamPlayer(team_id, is_captain) WHERE is_captain = 1; -- each team can have only 1 captain
```

It keeps both entities `Team` and `Player` separated and uses an associative table to define **all** relationships between them.

What I like about this design is that, once you have your teams and players, all transactions are done to that table only and all the constraints are set to that table only.
Sure, there are things to be concerned about, like when you change the captain of a team:
 first you must set the value of `is_captain` of the current captain to `0` and then change the value of `is_captain` of the new captain to `1`.

Which way you want to go, is a decision to make after you have addressed all your requirements, which I guess could go further than the definition of the captain of the team.